# Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 Internet not showing up on network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, network-manager, internet

Recently installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 on a PC made somewhere around 2010s, however when I try to install net-tools (or any package for that matter) it says `Temporary failure resolving ...` In my router config page it calls my server `ubuntu-server`, even though that is **not** the name of my PC (its *NEWCMC*). As far as I can tell I cannot connect to the internet or any other PC, I can't ping my router. Extra Info:

```
ip a:
1: lo <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisk noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:6f:65:76:d4:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Also if anyone knows how I can copy text (such as above) from my PC to my laptop *without* SSH (caus' I have no connection) could you please let me know so I don't have to type things out manually...
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you want to copy details but don't have networking, save the detail to a file & copy via thumb-drive to a machine connected to the internet etc  (where we'd use floppies or even tapes many decades ago.... ie. sneaker-net)

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, that was the one hassle i was trying to avoid, thanks anyway... Any ideas about my internet troubles?

Comment: I didn't really look sorry (busy on other things), is your networking hardware recognized?  (eg. `sudo lshw -C network` will list hardware of class networking) is where I'd look first.. If an enterprise grade machine I'd expect it to be good, cheaper consumer grade tends to have more issues.. Have you setup to use DHCP or static?  can you manually enable (UP) the port & set an ip address etc..

Comment: I’m no expert on networking but I did have to configure Netplan on my Ubuntu server. There is lots of documentation here. https://netplan.io/

Comment: @guiverc That commands shows my hardware info which is all correct however note that it says `*-network DISABLED` anything out of the ordinary? I have not set it up at all network wise however during installation it showed up the correct IP automatically. I have got it registered as a static IP in my *router* settings, is that not the right way to do it? (I have done it before with no problems)...

Comment: We can only see details the details that are provided.. If a network interface is DISABLED you have an issue as it won't be usable in that state.. If you want us to see that detail, you should add it to your question (you can edit your own question).

Answer (score 0):

Networking is handled by netplan by default in Ubuntu Server 17.10 and later. I suggest that you remove the existing but not working configuration:

```
sudo rm /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

Next, create a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Add the following:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses: 
        - 192.168.0.150/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 192.168.0.1]
```

Of course, substitute your exact details here.

Netplan is very specific about spacing and indentation so proofread carefully twice. Save(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) and exit the text editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>).

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

You will probably connect immediately. Check:

```
ip addr show
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

If you have the requested IP address and you get ping returns, then you are all set and you probably don’t require the net-tools package.

Answer (score 0):

Like most of my problems I was looking around on askubuntu.com and I stumbled upon something that gave me a few things which I did (Some were here https://netplan.io/) and now it works??? (only time will tell), my server shows up on router page, my static IP works, etc. I think it was just a temporary issue because today it works (I only thought it didn't because I put `sudo apt-get install ifconfig` instead of `net-tools`) So, to anyone who also has these issues, just wait it out is my advice. (Please let me know if I'm just being naive now.) Thanks to all who helped!! Edit: Just remembered what I did: I had previously followed a answer which said to edit some things in NetPlan, turns out I just had to change en01 to enp2s0. That fixed everything!